# MATLAB Eval - Need to use string inside

Tags: matlab

I need to evaluate the following statement `isfield(PKPD_1, 'gamma')` with `PKPD_1` being a variable that will change, and 'gamma' being a string.

So my first approach was `eval(['isfield(PKPD_' num2str(i) ', gamma'])`, but with this approach `gamma` becomes a variable and not a string.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You should look into trying to use something like a cell array rather than resorting to `eval`, so instead of calling say `isfield(PKPD_2, 'gamma')`, try structure your code so you can call `isfield(PKPD{2}, 'gamma')`. That way you don't need `eval` as you can go `isfield(PKPD{i}, 'gamma')`. I really highly recommend you do this if possible (and it's probably possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your question directly: use two single quotes to represent a single quote inside the eval expression.

```
eval(['isfield(PKPD_' num2str(i) ', ''gamma'')'])
```

But, as you may have already heard, eval is evil. In your case, you most probably don't need to use `eval`. As I do not know the context of your code, I think you should take a look at the MathWorks page about eval alternatives in Matlab. It may help you out: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html

cheers,
andré

Comment: There's a `)` missing at the end. Also in OP

Answer (score 2):

You are having a loop and trying to check whether PKPD_iterationnumber has gamma.

You can try this,for example:

```
for i=1:10
  eval(sprintf(isfield(PKPD_%d, 'gamma'),i));
end
```

But eval executes more slowly. Please read up on this: [Matlab Looping Variables](http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_create_variables_A1.2C_A2.2C....2CA10_in_a_loop.3F)

Answer (score 1):

Since your direct question has been answered, here's a suggestion of how to avoid using eval.
You might be able to use dynamic indexing instead.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html

If you made all your structs members of a single struct, you could loop like

```
for n = 1:length(bigStruct)
    subStructName = sprintf('PKPD_%d',n);
    isfield(bigStruct.(subStructName),'gamma');
end
```